# Refinerycms multiple languages dependent on TLD

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, refinerycms

I want to create a website with the refinerycms and now I have a question.
I have 4 domains for my website.

- mydomain.at
- mydomain.de
- mydomain.ch
- mydomain.com

In the beginning there only will be a german translation.

Now my question:

**Option 1:**

I do a redirect to mydomain.com and "map" the domains to:

- mydomain.com/de-at
- mydomain.com/de-de
- mydomain.com/de-ch

dependent on the country where the website is called.

**Option 2:**

I do not make a redirect an just show the content in the TLD. I just do a redirect dependent on the country, where the website is called.

For example website gets called in Germany over mydomain.at => I will redirect to mydomain.de

Now my question: How could I implement one of these options within the scope of the refinerycms?
I know the refinerycms-i18n gem and I also know the frontend locales and the normal "stuff". But I did not find anything about "multiple-same-languages" like "de-at", "de-de" and "de-ch". Because in the end all these translations are only one german translation, but the customer wants to specify the "sub-language" to make it more personal..

Anybody an idea?